# Declaring optional dependencies

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Given:

```
gulp.task("watch", function()
{
  // Asynchronous execution
  return gulp.src("...").
    doSomething1();
});

gulp.task("default", function()
{
    // Synchronous execution
    doSomething2();
    doSomething3();
});

gulp.task("css", ["csslint"]);
```

I would like `css` to run after `default` or `watch` completes but I can't declare `default` or `watch` as dependencies because that would trigger their execution.

**How do I declare an optional dependency? (run `css` after `default` or `watch` if they are already scheduled for execution, but don't schedule their execution).**

Comment: I gave you the wrong package name in our IRC chat.  See the correct package (or at least the one I use below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe gulp supports the concept of optional dependencies.  I believe what you need is [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence).  It'll allow you to do this:

```
var sequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('mySequence', sequence(
  ['task1', 'task2'], // ok to run these in parallel
  'task3' // will not run until 1 and 2 are both completed
));
```

It looks like [gulp v4 will address this shortcoming](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/355).

Comment: The documentation of https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence does not say that `sequence(['task1', 'task2'], 'task3')` is supported, but http://github.com/teambition/gulp-sequence does so I ended up using the latter. It seems to be more flexible anyway.

Comment: I think it does, assuming I'm reading it right: https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence#usage

Comment: Notice that they are invoking `runSequence` inside a function, as opposed to in place of a dependency list. I'm not sure the two forms are equivalent (it's not clear that `runSequence` returns a value).

Comment: Okay, I've tested both plugins. Neither one works properly when you specify them in place of dependencies. In other words, you need to rewrite dependencies in terms of `sequence()` invoked from inside the task callback function(). It's a pain in the ass but it works. I ended up using https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence (as you suggested) because it is more popular.

Comment: That's also why I chose it.